# Как установить Cisco Packet Tracer в Fedora?

Tags: linux, fedora, cisco-packet-tracer

Меня недавно спросили, как установить Cisco Packet Tracer в Fedora Workstation. И вообще, как его в Linux систему поставить, не обязательно этот дистрибутив?

Устанавливал я его давненько в Ubuntu 16.04 и то насколько я помню, с приключениями. По старой памяти попробовал сделать также, но этот способ не пошёл. Большая часть советов в русскоязычном сегменте сети по этому вопросу, не рабочие.

Ключевой проблемой является то, что после установки скрипта с программой, сама программа не запускается. Вводишь `packettracer` в терминале и тишина. Иконок с программой также никаких нет в системе, после установки.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как ни странно, в русскоязычном сегменте интернета не так-то и много пошаговых инструкций. Более опытный пользователь Linux без проблем разберется с этой задачей, но для менее опытного это проблема.

После установки скрипта с программой, сама программа не запускается, а причина простая, там не хватает определенных библиотек и файлов. Так давайте же разберемся с этим вопросом раз и навсегда.

**Шаг 1:**

Логинемся в [netacad](https://www.netacad.com/), в *Resources* выбираем *Download Packet Tracer*, далее выбираем *Linux Desktop Version 7.2.2 English* (на момент написания поста это актуальная версия). Если вы не меняли папку загрузки значит ваш установочный скрипт программы находится в *`~/Downloads.`*

**Шаг 2:**

Далее работаем в терминале, заходим в папку с загруженным файлом:

```
[user@fedora ~]$ cd Downloads
```

Смотрим тут ли наш файл и всё ли ок.

```
[user@fedora Downloads]$ ls -lh
```

**Шаг 3:**

Повышаем его права, чтоб его можно было установить.

```
[user@fedora Downloads]$ chmod +x PacketTracer-7.2.2-ubuntu-setup.run
```

**Шаг 4:**

Установка.

```
[user@fedora Downloads]$ sudo ./PacketTracer-7.2.2-ubuntu-setup.run
```

Вводим пароль суперпользователя.

**Шаг 5:**

Далее появится модальное окно, нажимаем *Next*, со всем соглашаемся и ждем завешения установки программы.

**Шаг 6:**

Проверяем установилась ли программа.

```
[user@fedora Downloads]$ packettracer
```

Если появилась надпись: `Starting Packet Tracer 7.2.2` и на этом всё закончилось, то мы на верном пути )

**Шаг 7:**

Проверяем, чего именно нехватает нашему приложению для запуска.

```
[user@fedora Downloads]$ ldd /opt/pt/bin/PacketTracer7 | grep not
```

В выводе вы увидите все недостающие элементы этого пазла.

**Шаг 8:**

Установим недостающие библиотеки.

```
[user@fedora Downloads]$ sudo dnf install qt5-qtwebkit qt5-qtmultimedia qt5-qtsvg qt5-qtscript libpng12
```

Вводим пароль `sudo` соглашаемся `Y` ждем окончания установки дополнительных библиотек.

**Шаг 9:**

Его можно пропустить, но для того чтоб вы убедились самостоятельно лучше выполните этот шаг, так как вы увидите что не всё что необходимо программе установлено.

```
[user@fedora Downloads]$ ldd /opt/pt/bin/PacketTracer7 | grep not
```

**Шаг 10:**

Недостающую `libcrypto` можно скачать [по ссылке с GitHub](https://github.com/sincorchetes/packettracer) или если вы пользуетесь git, то просто клонируйте себе прямо в папку `~/Downloads`. Не переживайте, после установки необходимых нам файлов это можно будет удалить.

```
[user@fedora Downloads]$ git clone https://github.com/sincorchetes/packettracer.git
```

Если закачиваете с помощью SSH пройдите по ссылке и замените путь на необходимый.

**Шаг 11:**

Зайдите в закачанную папку, где все файлы данного репозитория.

```
[user@fedora Downloads]$ cd /packettracer
```

Смотрим, что это за `bootstrap.sh` и не пугаемся, он выполняем простую примитивную команду, можете сделать то же самое вручную, я показываю с использованием этого микро-скрипта

```
[user@fedora packettracer]$ cat bootstrap.sh
```

**Шаг 12:**

Копируем с помощью скрипта недостающие файлы в нужные папки

```
[user@fedora packettracer]$ sudo ./bootstrap.sh
```

**Шаг 13:**

Проверяем, всё ли установилось, что нам необходимо для запуска программы

```
[user@fedora Downloads]$ ldd /opt/pt/bin/PacketTracer7 | grep not
```

Если ничего не вывело, значит всё установилось успешно.

**Шаг 14:**

Запускаем Cisco Packet Tracer в Fedora Workstation

```
[user@fedora Downloads]$ packettracer
```

Ура! Работает ) Наслаждаемся моментом.

**Шаг 15:**

Всё конечно классно, но через терминал постоянно запускать немного неудобно, давайте ещё внесем дополнительные изменения, чтоб у нас появилась иконка запуска в области приложений.

```
[user@fedora Downloads]$ sudo cp /opt/pt/bin/Cisco-PacketTracer.desktop /usr/share/applications/
```

Теперь в меню с приложениями у вас есть иконка запуска Cisco Packet Tracer с помощью которой можно удобно запускать программу.

Далее удалите все закачанные файлы из папки `~/Downloads` они вам больше не нужны.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**P.S:** Для тех у кого нет доступа в *netacad*, поюзайте сайт Cisco, там эту программу можно скачать сейчас бесплатно и пользоваться через гостевую сессию.

Update:

В новой версии Cisco Packet Tracer (7.3 и выше) доступна установка исключительно из .deb пакета. Решение уже найдено и проверено. Рассписано на ресурсе [ask.fedoraproject.org](https://ask.fedoraproject.org/t/how-to-install-new-cisco-packet-tracer-7-3-on-fedora-31-workstation/6047)

Comment: О, "тыжсетевик". А `GNS3` не ковырял?

Comment: ковырял, и EVE-NG )